# Why did Harry have to think so hard about how to breathe underwater?

Tags: harry-potter

In "Harry Potter and Goblet of Fire" Harry, Ron and Hermione go through countless books in the library to find out how Harry could breathe underwater. How come that the Bubble-Head Charm wasn't mentioned anywhere?